# Encryption algorithm: user only decrypt

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

What encryption algorithm can use 2 keys:
**admin - encrypt & decrypt**
and
**user - only decrypt** ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29) by using the private key for encryption (as if you would be signing).  The tuple `(d,n)` would be the admin key (normally named private key), `(e,n)` would be the user key (normally named public key).  The admin key is used for encryption, the user key for decryption.  Only the admin is in possession of the admin key, while both the user and the admin know the user key.  Now only the admin can encrypt, while the user can only decrypt.

Note that I deliberately chose the exponent `d` for the encrypting admin key and not vice-versa, because `e` is usually chosen to be very small for better performance, and if you'd do that with the admin key instead of the user key, then the system would be broken.

Note that if you construct a hybrid system for this, the desired decrypt-only property breaks, because the user can get to the symmetrical session key as well and modify the message.

I suspect you might want the decrypt-only property to actually achieve authentication of potentially large amounts of encrypted data (i.e. so that the user knows the data must come from the admin and has not been tampered with).  If so, what you really need is a more complex scheme with a proper digital signature (providing authentication) and some form of encryption for confidentiality, e.g. hybrid using a symmetrical cipher for bulk encryption and e.g. RSA for encryption of the symmetrical key.

However, you should be very careful when designing cryptographic systems like this, there are a **lot** of things which can go wrong and completely compromise the security of your system.  Seek expert advice.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: This is *incorrect* (see Daniel's comment).

You can modify any algorithm to allow two keys by generating a session key, using that to encrypt the payload, then using the two keys to each encrypt the session key.

For example, if `Ak` is the admin key, `Uk` is the user's key, `Sk` is a random session key, and `e(k, p)` is a symmetric encryption function, then you would use:

```
ciphertext = e(Ak, Sk) . e(Uk, Sk) . e(Sk, p)
```

Comment: Your proposal does not have the desired property that users can only decrypt. Since users can decrypt `Sk`, they can use `Sk` to encrypt a different payload `p'` and construct a new ciphertext from that.

Comment: D'oh! You are very right. Thanks. I'll leave my answer here as a warning of how not to do it.